# Objective C interface and C# core

Tags: xamarin.ios, ipad

I am trying to port a C# window's application to ipad.  I compiled everything on monotouch and it runs well.  Now, I need to make an iPad user interface.  If I implement the UI in Objective C, how hard is it to integrate it with my C# core? I saw monotouch can call objective C library, but I am doing the opposite direction.  Any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no support for you to execute the C# code from Objective-C. Your best bet is to just stay in MonoTouch and finish the iPad application with C#.

Working with UIKit in C# is at least as simple as it is with Obj-C, plus you get all the benefits of not having to deal with Memory allocation and the C# language and .NET framework. Developing UI code with lambda expressions and linq is a beatiful thing. Most obj-C sample code can be translated one-to-one to C# code, so almost every sample you find can be easily understood.

Answer (score 0):

There is one possibility, you make your UI into a library, then you bind the library to C#, and then your C# code calls your Objective-C code to the UI, and this one in turn, calls back to C# for its business logic.

You are better off doing the UI directly in C# as well.